# How to make bootable ISO of Mac OS X Snow Leopard Install DVD on Windows

Tags: mac, snow-leopard

I have tried ISOBuster and IMG Burn but I can't seem to make a Mac compatible ISO? All I can see is the boot camp partition (900MB) in both Windows and Linux. When I try and boot the ISO in VirtualBox (my intended goal) it tells me no bootable medium has been found.

Answer (score 1):

I read that you can use [MacDrive.app](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) (it is free for 5 days).

This is what they say about them self:

> MacDrive gives you complete control of a Mac disk all from your PC.
>
> You can access Mac disks from your desktop or favorite software, as
>   well as create and partition Mac disks. MacDrive even includes robust
>   tools to help repair Mac disks that are damaged or unreadable on other
>   computers.

The key is it can partition the disk in Mac OS stile, which is must have to make bootable OS disk.

Next step would be to open/extract the OS installer from the OS package (dmg) from your DVD an so on.